# Keeping an Image loaded until next selection within another userform

Tags: excel, vba

Not sure if this is possible but I have 2 Userforms.  1st form designates what image will be loaded into the 2nd form.  My issue is, when I close the 2nd form, the image disappears, even though the designated selection on the 1st form is still loaded. Basically, I want the image to stay loaded in 2nd form until a different selection is chosen on 1st form. This way the user can open and close the 2nd form without the image disappearing or having to re-select the same option.

My combobox is my selection control

RejectTitleNm = combobox
VASTEx = 2nd from (contains image)
Code has been inserted in my combobox Private Sub

```
 'got a match: get sample of pic from VAST folder
    VASTEx.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\VASTScreens\" & RejectTitleNm.Value & ".jpg")
      End If
```

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry correct code:

Comment: Vexamples.VASTEx.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\VASTScreens\" & RejectTitleNm.Value & ".jpg")

Comment: If you Hide the form instead of unloading it the picture will be retained.  If you unload the form then you must reload the picture.

Comment: think about it. you have an instruction that says: go to userform1 and get a filename, then load that file. ... but you cannot because userform1 has been destroyed.  .... it needs to be: go get filename that i saved after it was picked in userform1, then load that file

Comment: Thanks guys, I did some thinking of what you both said and came up with this, which works perfect!

Comment: Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode  As Integer)
  If CloseMode = 0 Then 'vbFormControlMenu = 0 ([X] button on top right), see MSDN
     Cancel = True 'Don't fire Terminate event...
     closeVAST_Click 'instead, call my close event handler
   End If
End Sub